# Good Resources on Operating/Administering MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

What are the best resources for learning how to **operate and administer MongoDB**?

There are plenty of resources on developing against it - which actually creates a problem when you've got plenty of development competence and really need to filter out that noise. For developers who can't afford to hire a DBA yet, we need to get reasonably good at keeping our Mongo cluster stable, performant, etc. Beyond the FAQs and quickstart guides, are there any other good repositories of info? Good blogs to follow, etc.?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best resource has to be the MongoDB docs themselves ...

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home

I'm constantly finding something new there.

Secondly, I'd say you should run the "try MongoDB" in browser tutorial available [here](http://try.mongodb.org/), it's awesome. You can try out querying and everything without installing anything.

http://try.mongodb.org/

Also, I'd personally recommend very highly these two tools:

- [MongoVUE](http://blog.mongovue.com/) (Windows MongoDB GUI)
- [RockMongo](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo) (PHP MongoDB interface, beats the pants off the others.)

You can also see my [stackoverflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269688/mongo-interface/4273399#4273399) for more details on MongoDB gui's also there are ***lots*** of videos available here: http://www.10gen.com/video

Lastly, you can check out http://learnmongo.com for a lot of beginners resources (full disclosure, I founded the site.)

Comment: Well, atleast you added your own site towards the end of the answer :) +1 for modesty!

Comment: Also free mongodb university courses very regularly.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing beats [MongoDB : The Definitive Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449381561) as a quick start guide.

[image: MongoDB : The Definitive Guide]

You can quickly learn many things, including

- install and start MongoDB
- why to kill -2 to shutdown and not kill -9
- how to enable the web interface
- how to shard

Advaned concepts will come with experience, practice, and data mining all the MongoDB blogs going forward.

Comment: I did find this book quite useful, until I spilled coffee on it :)

Comment: @Rex - LOL !!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

**Tools:**

- http://www.phpmoadmin.com/
- https://github.com/sbellity/futon4mongo

**Documentation:**

There is always the MongoDB website
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+Zone

**Blogs:**

- http://blog.mongodb.org/
- http://nosql.mypopescu.com/
- http://blog.boxedice.com/mongodb/

There was also the Mongo Conferences - for example slides from the one in the uk can be found at:

http://www.10gen.com/conferences/event_mongouk_18june10

Answer (score 0):

Here is another blog on [mongodb books](http://www.squidoo.com/mongodb-interview-questions)

They recommend on two books there (emphasis on horizontal scaling)

Including "MongoDB : The Definitive Guide"